# Spring Roo DBRE Primary Key Insert / Update

Tags: spring, primary-key, reverse-engineering, spring-roo

I am creating an application with Spring Roo. When I do a reverse engineer on a database table everything looks great but there are no fields for the primary keys, which are in the database. These are not auto incrementing but rather need to be filled manually or are drive off another table. When I launch my spring roo application I can create or view the tables and their fields but I can'r see primary key anywhere to view or update. Any advice on how to accomplish this?